# AWS Appsync working example in Swift of s3 image upload?

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-appsync

I'm following this tutorial here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/building-a-client-app-ios.html

I'm having some issues getting it to work, wondering if anyone has a working example.

Current issues:

1. Pods don't match up to the tutorial (awss3 and awsappsync require
   different versions of AWSCore (2.6.6 vs 2.6.12)
2. When using using different pod versions (apsync 2.6.7 and awss3 2.6.6) - the code generated by api-appsync-codegen
   doesn't compile - it doesn't create an S3Object class - but tries to
   extend it.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think i've got code that may work, but... alas it's blocked on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48999576/aws-appsync-getting-401s-from-ios-client

Comment: Hey, could you update if you are still facing this issue? Could you take a dependency on `AWSS3` `2.6.6`?

Comment: I got blocked on something else, will update when i have more data (probably in the next few weeks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AppSync SDK release of 2.6.14 fixes this issue. Now it takes dependency on latest available version of code. You should be able to run `pod install --repo-update` and be able to get the latest installation.

Thanks,
Rohan