# aws appsync - getting 401s from ios client

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-appsync

So when i run queries from the aws console, things work great.  However on my iOS client, i only get 401 errors.

I'm using the basic code from the tutorial and cognito auth:

```
    credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: AWSRegion, identityPoolId: CognitoIdentityPoolId)

    let databaseURL = URL(fileURLWithPath:NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(database_name)

    do {
        // Initialize the AWS AppSync configuration
        let appSyncConfig = try AWSAppSyncClientConfiguration(url: AppSyncEndpointURL, serviceRegion: AWSRegion, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider!, databaseURL:databaseURL)

        // Initialize the AppSync client
        appSyncClient = try AWSAppSyncClient(appSyncConfig: appSyncConfig)

        // Set id as the cache key for objects
        appSyncClient?.apolloClient?.cacheKeyForObject = { $0["id"] }
    }
    catch {
        NSLog("Error initializing appsync client. \(error)")
    }
```

I've tried hooking up the cognito sign in ui, which does seem to sign me in, but I still get 401 errors from the appsync client.

NOTE: using apikeybased auth also works fine - but cognito is needed for this project.

Any help would be appreciated, I'm banging my head on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have an inline policy on the IAM role for that Cognito Identity Pool that allows calls to your AWS AppSync API? It should look something like this:

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
      {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": [
            "appsync:GraphQL"
         ],
         "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:appsync:us-west-2:123456789012:apis/YourGraphQLApiId/*"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

You'll need to set this on the Authenticated and/or UnAuthenticated Cognito Role depending on how you setup your pool. More details of the IAM policies can be found here: [AppSync Security Guide - AWS_IAM Authorization](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/security.html#aws-iam-authorization)

**Additional answer**

It might be a good idea to level set some things for your setup. First go to the AWS AppSync console and for your API click the Settings tab on the left and select **AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM)** as the Authorization Type. Click Save. Then on your desktop install the awsmobile CLI:

```
npm install -g awsmobile-cli
```

Next go into your local application project directory, initialize it and add in Cognito via the `user-signin` feature:

```
cd ./my-project
awsmobile init                #select defaults
awsmobile user-signin enable
```

This will create & configure a new Cognito User Pool and Cognito Identity Pool automatically for you with AWS Mobile Hub. It will also setup correct IAM policies however at this time it doesn't configure AppSync policy and you will need to do that manually.

Open the IAM console and click Roles on the left hand side. In the search box type in the name of the project you created with the awsmobile CLI above. One of the roles will have a prefix of _auth_MOBILEHUB and one will have _unauth_MOBILEHUB. Depending on if you're logging in or just using Cognito in an unauthenticated state, the client will assume one of these roles at runtime. Select that role (or do this for both) and click Add inline policy and then the JSON tab. Enter in the below policy (JUST FOR TESTING):

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
      {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": [
            "appsync:GraphQL"
         ],
         "Resource": [
            "*"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Now if you're still getting 401 errors there is something else afoot in your service setup other than the client and you might want to open a ticket with AWS support. If however this is working now then you should make restrictions to this IAM policy so that it's not so permissive. I also recommend using a more restrictive policy for authenticated users.

Comment: I bet that’s it.   I thought that was missing and couldn’t figure it out.

Comment: OK,  this works for my calls that do not use lambda (the one that use dynamodb resolvers), but for the calls that do invoke lambda, i'm still getting a 401.  I tried adding permissions for the cognito user to invoke lambda, but thats not helping (or i'm doing it wrong)

Comment: Cognito user shouldn't need rights to invoke Lambda, only needs rights to invoke a field in your GraphQL API. AWS AppSync is the thing that has rights to invoke a Lambda function with a role that you set (or create) on the Data source page. So it could be: 1) the IAM policy for the resolvers on those fields isn't correct or 2) the role you've configured for the Lambda data source isn't correct. Quick test for process of elimination is to set DynamoDB for the resolver on that field, if it works then it's the role you've configured on that data source, if not then GraphQL API IAM policy.

Comment: Well crap, now it's failing again - is there a place where i can see attempts to contact appsync are getting rejected? or any logging on failures?   I worry theres some sort of rate limiting or failure thing happening with cognito.

Comment: I turned on the DD logging and it's saying "Value 'us-west-2_AOBLAH' at 'identityPoolId' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: ..."   Am I getting the wrong value for that pool ID value?  I was using the pool id from my cognito user pool

Comment: If i try using an ID from a cognito federated identity pool, then that still gives me a 401 error :(

Comment: You'll need to use the Cognito POOL Id, not an Identity ID. If you click "Edit Identity Pool" it will be listed at the top.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help @Richard.  I've cleaned it up a lot and it's still not working.  I'm able to sign in and out with cognito fine, however none of the appsync calls work (all returning a 401 without any messaging).    I've got my identity pool hooked up to my role (on both sides) and have tried a ton of different permutations on the policy, but nothing seems to work.  Hmm,  I'll post a new question with more context.

Comment: I gave an edit to help a bit more in the first answer

Comment: did you find any solution to this?  I am having the same issues using lambda as the datasource.  401 error even after setting the above inline policy on my auth_role

Comment: @MichaelEconomy Did this work? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Yeah, i got it working.  I’d make sure to turn on aws client logging and set your connection type to iam.   Make sure to clear the cache a lot, maybe start wth key based auth and make sure that works.  Good luck!